# Creating a react hook based on another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am relatively new to React Hooks, but familiar with class components.

I am trying to, on `onButtonPress()`, call `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)`, and take the output to response.

At that point, `useEffect()` should run.

```
const AppleAuthBtn = (props) => {

  let provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');
  provider.addScope('email');
  provider.addScope('name');

  let [response, onButtonPress] = firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (response && typeof props.onAuthenticate === 'function') {
      props.onAuthenticate(response, "Apple");
    }
  },[response])
  
  return(
<AuthButton 
      styles={[MainStyles.loginButton]}
      type='apple'
      icon={<MaterialCommunityIcons name="apple" size={26} color="black" style={{alignSelf: "center", justifySelf: "center", margin: 7}}/>}
      onPress={onButtonPress}
      buttonText={"Sign In with Apple"}        
    />
  )
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

Which makes sense - `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` is almost certainly generating only one object.

How do I write my hook in such a way that onButtonPress calls this function, and response gets the output?

Comment: Why don't you just have a setResponse that is called in a separate function that you attach to the button?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I was thinking something like that might be the right solution, but I wasn't sure if it was or if I was missing something with how hooks are supposed to work

Answer (score 1):

use useState to hold the response (`const [response, setResponse] = useState()`).

and set `onPress` to be a function that runs `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` and then uses `setResponse`.